MapServer Union layer : Legend not available
When I use the union layer, the legend is "not available".
I use the standard legend, not the html one.
When I use the layer separately the legend shows up well.
I tried also without the geotransform.
In MapServer I coud not find any documentation about the legend in the union layer page https://mapserver.org/mapfile/union.html
MAP
LEGEND
  STATUS ON
END
END

LAYER
    NAME "union"
    GROUP "group"    
    STATUS OFF
    CONNECTIONTYPE UNION
    CONNECTION "1,2"
    PROCESSING "ITEMS=1,2"
    TYPE POLYGON
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:32198"
    END

    LABELITEM "label"

    STYLEITEM "AUTO"
        CLASS
    END
END

LAYER
    NAME "1"
    GROUP "group"
    TYPE POLYGON

  PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:32198"
    END

    DATA "geom_s from table using unique id using srid=32198"

    LABELITEM "label"

    CLASS
        EXPRESSION ([column]  < 10 )
LABEL
...
END
        STYLE
...
        END
    END # CLASS
END

LAYER
    NAME "2"
    GROUP "group"
    TYPE POLYGON

  PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:32198"
    END

    DATA "geom_s from table using unique id using srid=32198"

    LABELITEM "label"

    CLASS
        NAME "Land"
        EXPRESSION ([column] >= 0)
        STYLE
            ...
        END
    END # CLASS
END``` 
Thank you!

